# Gorrila session filesystemstore cannot find session file

Tags: session, go, web-applications, oauth-2.0, gorilla

I'm starting to build a regular web app with golang and Angular2, and most importantly I'm trying to secure my login with the help of  [auth0.com](https://auth0.com). I download the quickstart code from [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/golang) and try to run the code,  it worked for a while and then next time I run it, the /tmp/session file cannot be found any more.

Here are some basic idea of the code auth0.com provides.
**1. Initialize the gorilla sessions filesystemstore**
**2. Then start the authentification process**
code is provided below

### app.go

```golang
var (
    Store *sessions.FilesystemStore
)

func Init() error {
    Store = sessions.NewFilesystemStore("", []byte("something-very-secret"))
    gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
    return nil
}
```

### login.go

```golang
func LoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    domain := os.Getenv("AUTH0_DOMAIN")
    aud := os.Getenv("AUTH0_AUDIENCE")

    conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     os.Getenv("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
        ClientSecret: os.Getenv("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
        RedirectURL:  os.Getenv("AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL"),
        Scopes:       []string{"openid", "profile"},
        Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
            AuthURL:  "https://" + domain + "/authorize",
            TokenURL: "https://" + domain + "/oauth/token",
        },
    }

    if aud == "" {
        aud = "https://" + domain + "/userinfo"
    }

    // Generate random state
    b := make([]byte, 32)
    rand.Read(b)
    state := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b)

    session, err := app.Store.Get(r, "state")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    session.Values["state"] = state
    err = session.Save(r, w)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    audience := oauth2.SetAuthURLParam("audience", aud)
    url := conf.AuthCodeURL(state, audience)

    http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}
```

The Error log is

### open /tmp/session_46CNLLHBKD... : no such file or directory

I try to understand the code and findout that error log comes from login.go line 39(session, err := app.Store.Get(r, "state")). And I started to track down the code and find out.
**login.go:39 -->store.go: 180-->session.go:132-->store.go:186-->store.go:272**
you can find [store.go](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go) and [session.go](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/sessions.go) here.
The error log comes from this line: **fdata, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)**
Through the whole process I have not found any function call to save the session file.

I don't understand this error and I don't know why I can run the code at the very beginning, please help me with this problem.
Your any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

#### I figure out the answer myself

**It turns out that I changed my secret key while initializing the gorilla session filesystemstore, but I have not deleted my cookie file in chrome, so it cannot find the tmp sesiion file needed.**
I change the key, then delete the coorsponding cookie file and everything is ok now.